# Emailing Multiple Attachments based on Named Range

Tags: vba, excel

Having trouble debugging the code below.

I'm trying to automate a macro to send multiple attachments based on a named range.

```
Sub Test()

 Dim objol As New Outlook.Application, objMail As MailItem
 Dim MyArr As Variant, i As Long

 Set objol = New Outlook.Application
 Set objMail = objol.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 With objMail
 MyArr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A9").Value
 .To = ("test@test.com")
 .Subject = "Test"
 .Body = ""
 .NoAging = True
 For i = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
 If Dir(MyArr(i, 1), vbNormal) <> "" Then .Attachments.Add MyArr(i, 1)
 Next i
 .Display
 End With

 End Sub
```

In the example I'm testing, I just have two inputs in the range ("Sheet2" and "Sheet3" in cells A2 & A3 respectively). It seems like the code acts up at `i=3` where the row is blank. But I need that to be okay. As the column it's referring to is set (A2:A9), the user puts in names of worksheets they want to email found in the workbook. Sometimes the user can input 2 names, or 3 names - any amount up to A9. I just need the code to End the looping if there's a blank in the range, and send the attachments already defined in the range.

As of now, it keeps giving me an type mismatch error? (Type mismatch happens at `If Dir(MyArr(i, 1), vbNormal) <> "" Then .Attachments.Add MyArr(i, 1)`

Edit - could also be an issue due to `Dir` - the values in the range are the sheet names, so Sheet1, Sheet2

Comment: There are two things going on here: **1)** If the values in `A2:A9` are literally *only* sheet names `Dir` will not work, neither will `.Attachments.Add`, as they both expect a valid file path name. **2)** To exit out of the loop when a cell is blank you can write `If myArr(i,1) = vbNullString` for example. There other ways to do it, including just loop through the range itself. Data set is so small it makes no real difference in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ScottHoltzman - why doesn't `Attachments.Add` take in Sheet names? Could something like this work: `Set rRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A9")

        For Each rcell In rRange
            If rcell.Value <> "" Then
                Sheets(rcell.Value).Copy

            End If
            Debug.Print rcell.Value`

Comment: If you Set an Object, you must Set it again to Nothing when you are done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want

```
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = "test@test.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Body = "Body"

        AddAttachments ActiveWorkbook, OutMail

        .Display
    End With


    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The following subroutine will loop from A2 to A9, then will call `SheetExists()` to see if the cell value matches an existing sheet name. If it does, it copies the sheet into a new workbook, saves it as a file in the temp folder, attaches it to the email and then deletes the file.

```
Sub AddAttachments(wb As Workbook, mail As Object)
    'Copy sheets
    For i = 2 To 9
        Dim sheetName As String
        sheetName = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value

        If SheetExists(sheetName, wb) = True Then
            wb.Sheets(sheetName).Copy

            Dim Destwb As Workbook
            Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

            Dim FileExtStr As String
            Dim FileFormatNum As Long

            'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
            With Destwb
                If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    'You use Excel 97-2003
                    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
                Else
                    'You use Excel 2007-2016
                    Select Case wb.FileFormat
                        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                        Case 52:
                            If .HasVBProject Then
                                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                            Else
                                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                            End If
                        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
                        Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
                    End Select
                End If

                'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
                Dim TempFilePath As String
                Dim TempFileName As String

                TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
                TempFileName = wb.Name & " " & sheetName & " " & Format(Now, "yymmdd h-mm-ss")

                .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum

                .Close savechanges:=False

                mail.Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

                'Delete the file you have send
                Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


 Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
 End Function
```

This is a quick solution. Notice I have not checked for errors i.e. I haven't checked if the file was created or not or I haven't checked if the same sheet is listed more than once which may give you undesirable results.

The extra effort is up to you

Comment: It seems I haven't Set Destwb = Nothing at the end of each loop. It is too late, that I will leave these extra little corrections to you.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it. I can work with the corrections. One last question, and feel free to direct me as much as you'd like - if I have a sheet that will always be sent along with the workbook containing the user defined sheets, such as "Sheet6". It will always be named "Sheet6" and always be in the workbook, and always sent in the email. Could I use Attachments.Add for that? Or is there a place where I could put `& "Sheet6"` essentially?

Comment: To add a particular sheet like "Sheet6", you need to copy some of the code from `AddAttachments()` sub. Yes you need to use Attachements.Add, like AddAttachements() does with `mail.Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr`, but first it copies the Sheet into a new Workbook, save it somewhere in the hard drive (temp folder), and then it is ready to be attached with Attachements.Add. The code you need is inside the `For` statement. Just copy the code, making sure `sheetName = "Sheet6"`

Comment: I've adjusted the code to contain:     `For i = 2 To 11
        Dim sheetName As String
        sheetName = wb.Sheets("Inputsheets").Range("B" & i).Value
        sheetName2 = "Sheet6"

        If SheetExists(sheetName, wb) = True Then
            wb.Sheets(sheetName).Copy
            wb.Sheets(sheetName2).Copy` The non-adjusted code gives me back two separate attachments for the two different user defined sheet names (sheet1 & sheet2) - with the adjusted code in this comment, it will give me back Sheet 6 & Sheet2 in two diff excel files if I click on the second attachment. cnt ->

Comment: Is there a way to return all 3 files in one workbook, or to have them save in 3 different file? Not sure why sheet6 is combining with the second attachment as opposed to being it's own attachment

Comment: If you want to copy Sheet6, it needs to be outside the For statement, otherwise it will iterate 8 times. Yes you can copy each sheet to only one workbook and then attach it

Comment: Got it. So I did place it out of the iteration, and had the same issue. It was generating once, but within the second attachment as opposed to it's own attachment?

Comment: Please ask another question, so you can show us what are you doing